# How do I select "this" in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, this

I have 5 buttons using the same ng-click function. Basically each of the buttons operate similarly to a tabbed navigation, where you click one of the buttons and it takes you to that tab's pane. Each of these buttons can be repeatable and are housed in a template. The tab panes are also all in a template but aren't all active until a user clicks one of the buttons and creates a page. So basically there are multiple click functions nested within click functions that do different things depending on what user has activated.

In jQuery, I could just use "this" and select the object that was clicked and do all my manipulations to that object easily; however, it doesn't appear there's a way to do that using just angular. Currently, when you click one of these buttons it does the same thing to all of them. I figure I could create 5 separate functions, but I don't want to do that for scalability reasons.

So to summaraize:

- Is there a way to select "this" in Angular?
- I'd like a solution that is just using Angular and no jQuery
- Is there an efficient way of dealing with click functions within click functions?

  ```
  <nav class="block--menu">
  <section class="content--menu" ng-controller="ActiveCtrl">
      <div class="menu" >
          <button  class="menu__item" ng-click="showConfirm()"></button>
          <button  class="menu__item" ng-click="showConfirm()"></button>
          <button  class="menu__item" ng-click="showConfirm()"></button>
          <button  class="menu__item" ng-click="showConfirm()"></button>
          <button  class="menu__item" ng-click="showConfirm()"></button>
      </div>
  </section>
  ```

Comment: please add some code showing what you have tried to do

Comment: `I'd like a solution that is just using Angular and no jQuery` nobody is going to do your job for you. Show us your progress so we can help you.

Comment: If you regularly need access to the element in your controller code, you're writing angular incorrectly.  You should consider writing a directive where the element is already established, which would give you whatever you might need.

Comment: example has been added. I had trouble getting it to show when I originally posted. I'm not expecting anyone to write it for me, but I also can't write something I don't know how to do.

Comment: @jmur you still haven't shown that you are actually trying to accomplish!  In what way are you manipulating what elements?

Comment: @jmur, you might benefit from reading this [How to think in Angular](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15012542/968155) answer - it describes how to make the app model-driven - it's quite rare that one would need the DOM object in the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stop thinking in a jQuery way and don't try to manipulate the DOM directly. In your controller you should only manipulate the data, which is then reflected in the view. When you think Angular-way, your code usually looks as follows:

**HTML**

```
<section ng-controller="ActiveCtrl as ctrl">
    <div class="menu" >
        <button ng-repeat="button in ctrl.buttons track by $index"
                ng-click="ctrl.showConfirm(button)"
                ng-class="{'menu__item_active':button.active, 'menu__item':true}"
        >{{button.name}}</button>
    </div>
</section>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app',[]).
  controller('ActiveCtrl', ['$window', function($window) {
    this.buttons = [{
      name: 'First'
    }, {
      name: 'Second'
    }, {
      name: 'Third'
    }];
    this.showConfirm = function(button) {
      button.active = !button.active;
      $window.alert(button.name);
    }
  }]);
```

**Plunker**

http://plnkr.co/edit/Dg10cXqFxEKgEt7jWQ7Z?p=preview

Comment: This was a lot more inline with what I was thinking. This definitely gave me enough to get started. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can access jQuery event object using `$event` in angular events [check the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-) for details but if you are sending that to your controller it most likely means you are not doing it in [angular way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background).

the usage is

```
<button  class="menu__item" ng-click="showConfirm($event)"></button>
```

and in the controller

```
$scope.showConfirm = function($event){
    //$event.target should be your link
};
```

Comment: This isn't an answer.

Comment: Good... but `this` is actually not `$event` - `this` is the scope object, i.e. `showConfirm(this)` sends the scope object to the function - so that statement is incorrect

Comment: what the OP meant was this in jquery events not this in angular. "In jQuery, I could just use "this" and select the object that was clicked"

Comment: Perhaps... I would suggest rephrasing to avoid confusing

Comment: @NewDev how about now?